# MSTest Timeout attribute not working as expected

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, attributes, mstest

Why can't i use const values in timeout attribute, example:

```
private const int TIME_OUT = 1000;

[TesMethod]
[Timeout(2 * TIME_OUT)]
public void testA(){
  while(true);
}
```

Editing after comments:

It compiles but never stops in "timeout seconds"

Comment: This compiles just fine with C#4.0 in Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: This compiles just fine with C#4.0 in Visual Studio 2012

Comment: @Iain I already answered my question. It's a bug in VS 2008 that was fixed in VS2010. So C# 4.0 in VS2012 is working already. Just an old bug in Visual Studio. Thats all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug in Visual Studio 2008 and this bug was fixed in VS2010

Answer (score 2):

Are you running the test under the debugger?  If so, then timeouts are disabled when under the debugger.  Running from VS (not under debugger) or commandline should have timeouts enabled.

Comment: I know that, I´m not debugging. :(